# Homebrew Cask cannot find custom formula

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I'm trying to get a homebrew-cask repo working. The repository is already set up at https://github.com/skysquirrel/homebrew-cask and the formula is at `Casks/qgis-ltr-simple.rb`.

At this point it seems like `brew install skysquirrel/cask/qgis-ltr-simple` should work, but it doesn't:

```
$ brew install SkySquirrel/cask/qgis-ltr-simple
==> Tapping skysquirrel/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/skysquirrel/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Tapped 1 cask (28 files, 24KB).
Error: No available formula with the name "skysquirrel/cask/qgis-ltr-simple"
```

However it does appear with `brew cask info`:

```
$ brew cask info skysquirrel/cask/qgis-ltr-simple
==> Tapping skysquirrel/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/skysquirrel/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Tapped 1 cask (28 files, 24KB).
qgis-ltr-simple: 2.18.24-1
https://qgis.org/
Not installed
...
```

And it does appear with `brew search`:

```
$ brew search qgis-ltr-simple
==> Casks
qgis-ltr-simple
```

It seems I can do this instead:

```
brew tap skysquirrel/cask
brew install qgis-ltr-simple
```

But I'd like to find out why the one liner isn't working.